# Best robotic camera mount for 'high speed' panning?

Tags: camera, filming

I see all of these robot panning mounts, but all of them are for time lapses and are very slow. I simply need to replace the human hand with something more exact.

I need a camera mount that can turn 90 degrees at a constant speed in a short amount of time (1-2 seconds) and with good precision. It would preferably have options to adjust the speed and tell me the angle the camera is currently facing.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Welcome! What is your budget? What is the weight of the camera you want to mount? Do you need to integrate with an existing control system?

Comment: Budget is $1000 or so, camera weight is a couple pounds (cannon eos 70d) and I dont need to integrate it with a existing control system